# JPA 2.0 Simple @OneToOne mapping fails on insert

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I am trying to create a simple JPA 2.0 style unidirectional mapping. The object model is simple

One User can have One Address.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="user_seq",sequenceName = "sequence",allocationSize=1) 
@GeneratedValue (generator="user_seq",strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name="userid")
private Long userId;

@Column(name="emailid")
private String emailId;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Address address;

public User() {

}

public Long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}


public String getEmailId() {
    return emailId;
}

public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
    this.emailId = emailId;
}


public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}


}

@Entity
@Table(name="address")
public class Address {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="address_seq",sequenceName =               "hibernate_sequence",allocationSize=1) 
@GeneratedValue (generator="address_seq",strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private long id;


@Column(name="userid")
private long userId;

@Column(name="address")
private String completeAddress;



public Address() {
    super();
}



public Address (String completeAddress) {
    super();
    this.completeAddress = completeAddress;
}



public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getCompleteAddress() {
    return completeAddress;
}

public void setCompleteAddress(String completeAddress) {
    this.completeAddress = completeAddress;
}



}
```

This is what I am trying to execute to create a new user and set the address on that user.

```
EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
 EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
 try {
     tx.begin();
     User user = new User();
     user.setEmailId("test123");
     Address address = new Address();
     address.setCompleteAddress("some address");
     user.setAddress(address);
     em.persist(user);
     tx.commit();
 } catch (Exception e) {
     em.getTransaction().rollback();
 } finally {
     em.close();
 }
```

This is the error I get -

```
[EL Warning]: 2013-02-04 16:00:03.376--UnitOfWork(1827795025)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.0.v20091127-r5931): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "address" violates foreign key constraint "address_userid_fkey"
  Detail: Key (userid)=(0) is not present in table "users".
  Error Code: 0
  Call: INSERT INTO address (ID, userid, address) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
bind => [43, 0, some address]
  Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.jpa.test.Address@5c001eb0)
```

The error is very basic and states that the userid value is not getting set on the address record. Seems like there is enough information for the persistence manager here to make this simple transaction happen. What has gone wrong in the mapping?

Comment: So apparently the persistence manager does not like the foreign key from the child table mapped to the corresponding object. Since the relationship is unidirectional, it enforces the navigability only from parent to child. So having the foreign key not exposed on the child will ensure that there is no way to find and/or navigate the child directly w/o the parent.

So in the example above, all that was required was to remove 

@Column(name="userid")
private long userId;
    public long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

Comment: Ok, removing that gets me past the insert but its actually of no use. The user_id does not get persisted in the address table. So in effect this comes in as a null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Address has userid which you are not setting.  It needs to be set to user's id manually unless you are going to set a one to one relation mapping from Address to User.  Set up a onetoone with a join column mapping the userid field, and mark the user->address was mappedby the new relation. See http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.0/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html for examples

Comment: The UserId is not available to be set in this context. It's always empty since it has not been assigned yet.

Comment: Either persist and flush user to get an ID assigned that you can use for the field or change the type from long to Long so null can be inserted until you can set it.  But the field is being controlled by address' userid attribute which is why you get 0 inserted.  You need a mapping from address to User to have the provider set the value for you.

Comment: Yes, that will work. However the model itself is flawed. A OneToOne relationship like this is never really enforced at the DB level. You did answer the question that was posed so I have to give it to you.

Answer (score 0):

What I was doing wrong was defining the relationship that allowed for OneToMany but trying to model it as a OneToOne relationship.

I should have a address_id column on the User table and not a user_id on the address table. If I define the address_id column on the User table and map my entity like this

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name="address_id")
//@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Address address;
```

it works just fine. This is the way the persistence manager is expecting a OneToOne relationship defined.